# From ExtJS tab, select next tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I want to disable a tab and if it is active, automatically jump to the next tab.

I tried

```
myPanel.tab.disable();
if(myPanel.tab.active)
    myPanel.NextSibling().tab.setActive();
```

and

```
myPanel.tab.disable();
if(myPanel.tab.active)
    myPanel.tab.NextSibling().setActive();
```

but neither worked, chrome always crying because the `NextSibling()` method does not exist.

So, how do I select the next tab?

Comment: For further reference: As per the ExtJS docs, it's `nextSibling()`, not `NextSibling()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tab index to do it, you should also check if it is the last tab in the tabs order, if it is I usually set the first tab:

```
myPanel.getActiveTab().disable();
var index = myPanel.items.indexOf(myPanel.getActiveTab());
if(index < myPanel.items.length-1) myPanel.setActiveTab(index + 1);
else myPanel.setActiveTab(0);
```